# Understanding vector bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

I am going through Nakahara's book "Geomety, topology and physics" on my own to prepare for my bachelor thesis. I got stuck on vector bundles, specially the local trivialization.

If I have a local trivialization, $\phi: U_i\times F\rightarrow \pi^{-1}(U_i)$, where $\pi: E\rightarrow M $  is the projection between the total space and base space. What is then the difference between $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ and $\phi(p,f)$?

Furthermore, the book dosen't really go into any detail how one should do the explicit calculation for the trivialization, I have tried to find information online but I could not find anything. I have tried to determine explicitly the local trivializations for an example in the book.

$$L:=\{(p,v)\in \mathbb{C}P^n\times\mathbb{C}^{n+1}|v=ap, a\in\mathbb{C} \} $$
I have been able to figure out that the fibre is a line in $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ over $ \mathbb{C}P^n$, the transition function is $t_{ij}=z_i/z_j$ and that the group structure is $U(1)$. But I have no idea how to explicitly determine the local trivialization.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ is a set and $\phi(p,f)$ is an element of the set.

Comment: The fiber is not $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. It is a line.

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote. It has been corrected.

Comment: Set $n=1$, can't you find an isomorphism between $L$ restricted to $\mathbb{C}$ (viewed as the complement of $\infty$) and $\mathbb{C}\times \mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @A.rod Do you mean $L$ restricted to $\mathbb{C}P$?

Comment: No, I do mean $L$ restricted to $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{C}P\setminus \{\infty\}$

Comment: @A.Rod I don't think I can.

Comment: How about the map $\mathbb{C}P\setminus\{\infty\}\times \mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}P\setminus\{\infty\}\times \mathbb{C}^2$ that maps $([z:1],t)$ to $([z:1], t.(z,1))$?

Comment: @A.Rod I tried but I am very sure that I did not get the correct answer. How do you in general go about constructing maps? Unfortunately my book dosen't go into any detail at all in explicit calculation. I also dont understand why there is only $\mathbb{C}$ and not $\mathbb{C}^2$ on the left hand side. Should not $\pi^{-1}(U_i)$ be in E?.... I fear I am misunderstanding quite a bit here.

Comment: On the left hand side you should have something like $base \times fiber$. Here, as I told you earlier, the fiber is a line, so you should have smth like $U_i\times \mathbb{C}$. Here you only need two open sets to trivialize your bundle $\mathbb{C}P-\{\infty\}$ and $\mathbb{C}P-\{0\}$ or any open set containing the infinity.

Comment: @A.Rod Thanks for explaining that to me! So obvious now :/. Do you mind explaning how to derive the correct map?